# how to display a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple football twitter 'bot' by fun, here is the code:

```
def NewTweet (player, action, success):
    tweet = player + ' plays a ' + action + '.'

    if (success):
        if action == 'pass':
            tweet += ' The team keeps possession'
        elif action == 'shot':
            tweet += ' GOOOOAAAAALLLLL'
    else:
        if action == 'pass':
            tweet += ' The pass is unsuccessful'
        elif action == 'shot':
            tweet += ' The shot goes wide'

    return tweet

NewTweet ('Bruno', 'shot', True)
```

Why doesn't it print out as 'Bruno Fernandes plays a shot. GOOOALLL' when I run it in terminal on VSCode?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Because you didn't put `print` anywhere.

Comment: Your function builds a string, it does not print anything. You can simply wrap the function call in a print: ``print(NewTweet ('Bruno', 'shot', True))`` or store the result in a variable and then print that variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are returning the tweet variable instead of used **print** keyword which will print the tweet.
i.e `print(tweet)`

Comment: Instead of writing `return tweet`, write like this `print(tweet)` or you can also write like this `print(NewTweet ('Bruno', 'shot', True))` and return the tweet value in this case

Comment: No, @HarshilKansagara `return tweet`  is better to use. So, you can do `print(NewTweet(...))`